# React-Native: access a function defined inside useEffect() - call it from outside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

Is there any way of calling a function (as a callback of a button) that was defined inside useEffect?

The skeleton of the component is as follows:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const longFunction = async () => {
    ...
    const innerFunctionOne = async () => {
       ...
    }
    const innerFunctionTwo = async () => {
       ...
       innerFunctionOne()
    }

    ... some code
    ... some code
    innerFunctionTwo()
  }

  ...some code
  longFunction();
  
  return someCleanup;

},[])

...
...
<Button onPress={() => innerFunctionTwo()}
```

Apart from taking out the function definition outside of useEffect, is there a way of accessing it from the Button?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without knowing the details of the implementation. So without knowing your details, I would put the longFunction outside the useEffect and the innerFunctionTwo outside the longFunction. For example:

```js
function App() {
  const innerFnTwo = function() {
    console.log('innerFnTwo');
  };

  const longFn = function() {
    console.log('longFn');
    innerFnTwo();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    longFn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => innerFnTwo()}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - in the end I ended up moving it to a custom hook.

Comment: @Wasteland right, it is a good decision to put it in a custom hook if you gonna use that logic in many components through the app.